# How do you move an object from one array to another array by feature?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, state

I am trying to move an object from one array to another. Think of it like adding / moving a friend from non-friend to friend. I have two arrays, which can be seen below, and I am trying to move an object (i.e. a friend) from possible to current via it's 'id'. In the below example, I am trying to move Parker from possible to current with id = 2.

```
state = {
    current: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'peter'
        }
    ],
    possible: [
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'parker'
        }
    ]
}


function addFriend(state, action) {
  const { current, possible } = state;
  const addedFriend = Object.assign(
    {},
    state.possible.splice(action.payload.index, 1)
  );

  current.push(addedFriend);

  const newState = { current, possible };
  return newState;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can remove multiple elements with `splice()`, it returns an array. Index the result to get the specific object. You don't need to use `Object.assign()`, that just copies the value (which just converts the array into an object whose properties are the array indexes).

```js
var state = {
    current: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'peter'
        }
    ],
    possible: [
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'parker'
        }
    ]
};

function addFriend(state, action) {
  const { current, possible } = state;
  const addedFriend = state.possible.splice(action.payload.index, 1)[0];

  current.push(addedFriend);

  const newState = { current, possible };
  return newState;
}

state = addFriend(state, {payload: { index: 0 }});
console.log(state);
```

I'm not sure why you're returning a new `state` object, since you're modifying the old state in place.

Comment: Currently current is resulting in:
{ current: [ { id:1, name: 'peter' }, { 0: { id:2, name: 'parker' } } ] } - i somehow need that 0 to disappear. 
1) The reason I am returning new state is because I am using redux, and a don't want to duplicate state. 2) I'm using Object.assign() to try an combat the problem above...

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to do it without `Object.assign`.

Comment: @Barmar This works but I think you are mutating the state when you are creating `addedFriend` variable.

Comment: `current.push()` mutates the state, I took that from your original code.

Comment: how would you do it via id (not via index?)

Comment: `index = state.possible.find(el => el.id == id)`

Answer (score 0):

It is not that time-efficient if you want a fast running code. But it follows immutability.

We just ignore the item from `possible`, and add it to `current`.

```js
state = {
    current: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'peter'
        }
    ],
    possible: [
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'parker'
        }
    ]
}


function addFriend(state, action) {
  const { current, possible } = state;
  return {
    ...state,
    current: current.concat(possible[action.payload.index]),
    possible: possible.filter((_, index) => index !== action.payload.index)
  }
}

state = addFriend(state, {payload: {index: 0}})
console.log(state)
```